# max wait time on the linux scheduler run-queue

Tags: linux

I'm doing a school project on linux scheduler. Is there any counter or stats that can give the max wait time on the scheduler's runqueue for a certain process? I'm using centos 7. It seems that the /proc/process_id directory only contains info for the average wait time, not the max.

Comment: The se.statistics.wait_max line in /proc/pid/sched isn't what you want?

Comment: Thanks, that's what I need. How often is the /proc/pid/sched updated? Is it updated every time the process is scheduled?

Comment: also what's the unit for se.statistics.wait_max? Thanks!